# Java How to wait for a clip to end

Tags: java, audio, wait

I am trying to play a few small sound effects, and I'm doing this via a method that loads the clip, plays it, and should then close the clip to allow a new one to be loaded later on without causing any LineUnavailable issues. Here's the method I use:

```
public void playClip(String filename){

    Clip clip = null;

    try{

        AudioInputStream inputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(getClass().getResource(filename));
        AudioFormat format = inputStream.getFormat();
        DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, format);
        clip = (Clip)AudioSystem.getLine(info);
        clip.open(inputStream);
        clip.start();

    }catch(Exception e){

        e.printStackTrace();

    }

}
```

Right now, following `clip.start()`, the clip just remains somewhere, using up a line, until I get the following error:

```
javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException: line with format PCM_SIGNED 44100.0 Hz, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, little-endian not supported.
at com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice$DirectDL.implOpen(DirectAudioDevice.java:513)
at com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice$DirectClip.implOpen(DirectAudioDevice.java:1304)
at com.sun.media.sound.AbstractDataLine.open(AbstractDataLine.java:121)
at com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice$DirectClip.open(DirectAudioDevice.java:1085)
at com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice$DirectClip.open(DirectAudioDevice.java:1175)
at com.andrewlalisofficial.ChatClientCore.playClip(ChatClientCore.java:233)
at com.andrewlalisofficial.ChatClientWindow$4.mouseClicked(ChatClientWindow.java:207)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6519)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3312)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6281)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4872)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4501)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:747)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:706)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:704)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:720)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:718)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:717)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException: line with format PCM_SIGNED 44100.0 Hz, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, little-endian not supported.
    at com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice$DirectDL.implOpen(DirectAudioDevice.java:513)
    at com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice$DirectClip.implOpen(DirectAudioDevice.java:1304)
    at com.sun.media.sound.AbstractDataLine.open(AbstractDataLine.java:121)
    at com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice$DirectClip.open(DirectAudioDevice.java:1085)
    at com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice$DirectClip.open(DirectAudioDevice.java:1175)
    at com.andrewlalisofficial.ChatClientCore.playClip(ChatClientCore.java:233)
    at com.andrewlalisofficial.ChatClientWindow$4.mouseClicked(ChatClientWindow.java:207)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6519)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3312)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6281)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4872)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4501)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:747)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:704)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:720)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:718)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:717)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)

How would I add `clip.close()` after the clip finishes?

Comment: You could use `Clip#drain`, but I've had issues with using this in the past and have instead used a `LineListener` instead, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29836255/playing-multiple-sound-clips-using-clip-objects/29836764#29836764)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding finally block to close connection

`finally {    if (clip!= null) {
try {  clip.close() 
     } catch (Exceptione e) { /* ignored */}
    }`