# How to stop audio sound from overlapping when button is clicked?

Tags: java, javasound

**Problem description:** I have an array of sounds files with different length. Every time the `Play` button is clicked, I want one sound be played. The problem is that when the `Play` button is clicked twice (or more times), the next sound starts and overlaps the currently playing sound. I don't want to `clip.stop()`the current sound, I want the next sound not to start until the current sound is finished. I have tried different approaches, like `boolean flag`, `clickCount` and checking the `Clip.isRunning();`status, but they not really getting me to where I want. I also saw someone else having similar issue in OS (with `MultiPlayer()` though), but his problem was resolved AFAIK. Any suggestion would be appreciated!

Here is related code:

```
public class PlaySounds {
private AudioInputStream audioStream;
public static Clip clip;
private URL url;
public static int nextSound;

public void playAllSounds() {
    for (String str : soundList) { // arrayList of sounds
        str = soundList.get(nextSound);
        url = getClass().getResource(str);
    }
    try {

        audioStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(url);
        clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        clip.open(audioStream);
        clip.start();

    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

 }
}
```

Main class file:

```
PlaySounds ps = new PlaySounds();
int next = 0;
List<Integer> positions = new ArrayList<>();
 /*Some other methods....
....
*/
    private void getshuffledPositions() {

    for (int i = 0, i <=12; i++) {
        positions.add(i);

    }
    Collections.shuffle(positions);

}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

    if (ae.getSource() == playButton) {
        //Some codes.....Here I tried boolean flag, etc
        ps.nextSound = positions.get(next);
        ps.playAllSounds();
        //Some more codes.....
```

Comment: I meant SO, not OS :)

Comment: Call stop on the current instance of the clip

Comment: @MadProgrammer I don't believe the OP wants to stop the running clip: "_I don't want to `clip.stop()` the current sound, I want the next sound not to start until the current sound is finished_".

Comment: @sumu You can [edit] your question to fix any mistakes.

Comment: In that case, use a LineListener, when the clip finishes, pick the next item out of a queue

Comment: @MadProgrammer, exactly, I don't want the running clip to stop, instead, I want the next sound to wait until it finishes with the current sound.

Comment: [For example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29836255/playing-multiple-sound-clips-using-clip-objects/29836764#29836764)

Comment: @MadProgrammer, thanks for example, I will try that out soon....